# R barplot legend in center

Tags: r, plot, legend

I have a barplot which looks like as:
[image]

and I want to add a legend somewhere in the bolded rectangle, I have already tried par(xpd=TRUE) and setting the margins for the fourth bar plot but for some reasons I can't get it to work...

So if you have any idea please let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why `xpd` didn't work for you, but the following piece of code should give you some clues:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2), xpd=TRUE)
barplot(tN, col = 2:3)
barplot(tN, col = 2:3)
barplot(tN, col = 2:3)
barplot(tN, col = 2:3)
legend(-4.5, 56,  c("A", "B"), col=2:3,lwd=1)
```

To get an idea of the legend's coordinates, I used the `locator()` function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `layout` here, with different heights
[image]

```
layout(rbind(c(1, 2),
             c(3, 3),
             c(4, 5)),
       heights=c(3, 1.5, 3),
       respect=FALSE)
tN <- table(Ni <- stats::rpois(100, lambda = 5))
barplot(tN, col = 2:3)
barplot(tN, col = 2:3)
plot.new()
#box()
text(0.5,0.5,'legend in center',cex=3)
barplot(tN, col = 2:3)
barplot(tN, col = 2:3)
```

Answer (score 1):

try `locator {graphics}`

```
?locator

legend(locator(1), border=FALSE, fill=FALSE, "try the position")
```

after your plot(), you can click on your plot window on the position you wish